# Redirect domain when there isn't a subdomain with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When someone types `http://example.com` I need it to be redirected to `http://www.example.com` but if someone goes to `http://somenthing.example.com` it should not be redirected.

I've been trying different rules with no luck, can anyone point to me the right htaccess rule to use here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule (place it on the top of your .htaccess .. as order of rules matters):

```
RewriteEngine On

# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```